# Is it possible to install Android to a web server and run a Virtual Android OS as a web app

Tags: android, android-emulator, virtualization

Is there any way to run Android as a webapp?  Either by installing an emulator or something like the [Android-x86](http://www.android-x86.org/) or [Live-Android](http://code.google.com/p/live-android/) projects on a web server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you should define what qualifies as a "web app" ?

For example, I'm pretty sure the (linux version of) the android emulator already works over X11, meaning the display and user input can be from a remote machine (running any modern OS) across the network from the one doing the computation.  Maybe that doesn't sound like a web app to you since the client isn't a web browser, but hypothetically one could write a crude X server as a java applet to run in the browser, so wouldn't it qualify then?

Ultimately there are many ways to do this - run a bunch of instances of ARM or X86 android on some kind of VM (or how about a cluster of beagleboards?), then come up with a scheme to remote the user interface using something homegrown or based on X or VNC or whatever strikes your fancy.

I believe are also commercial services such as deviceanywhere that let your remotely test your program on a variety of real smartphones exactly matching the configuration an end user would have.

Answer (score 1):

If one brave soul moves the Android Emulator into a Webstart / Applet application you might be lucky.

As of now the requirements are too high and nobody did it.

Comment: When you say the "requirements are too high" do you mean the steps to complete it are to numerous and difficult or the required specs needed to run such an app would be too great?  If it's the former, roughly what are we looking at? (I don't expect you to list every step, just trying to get an idea of what it would take)

Comment: You would need an container to run the SDK & Emulator. Probably some Tomcat would do. Then, you need permissions to have it compile stuff & execute the Android toolchain. I have no idea how long this would take, as the SDK is quite big. For standard stuff, maybe u have to spend 1 to 2 months and read a lot about class loading, web app security etc etc.